# Report-bulk-objects in Adobe Connect

Tags: adobe, adobe-connect

I would like to get a list of meetings on the server however when i do a https://example.com/api/xml?action=report-bulk-objects&filter-type=meeting replacing the domain with my connect domain i get an access denied response. I am signed in to the connect work space and I am in the admin group. What could be the cause of this?

response:

```
<results>
    <status code="no-access" subcode="denied"/>
</results>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you're in the admin group, logged in, and submitting the request from the same browser that's logged in. You might try adding the session parameter to your request ("&session=*breez123abc456def*")

The value of the parameter must be that of the BREEZESESSION cookie set by the Connect server on your authenticated session. One of several ways to discover that is with the common-info API method: https://connect.example.com/api/xml?action=common-info It'll be in the /results/common/cookie element.

If this still isn't working, check the debug.log on the server(s) for the failing request; there should be additional information there.